# react-bootstrap-tabs library, compliation error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

getting in trouble with https://github.com/freeranger/react-bootstrap-tabs library, used for Tab creation at React

My code which is work:

```
<Tabs onSelect={(index, label) => console.log(label + ' selected')}>
                            <Tab label="TEST">
                                <div className="table-scrollable table-scrollable-borderless">
                                    <table className="table table-hover table-light">
                                        <thead>
                                            <tr className="uppercase">
                                                <th> # </th>
                                                <th> First Name </th>
                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td> 1 </td>
                                                <td> Mark </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                            </Tab>
                            <Tab label="TEST2">
                                <div className="table-scrollable table-scrollable-borderless">
                                    <table className="table table-hover table-light">
                                        <thead>
                                            <tr className="uppercase">
                                                <th> # </th>
                                                <th> First Name </th>
                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td> 1 </td>
                                                <td> Mark </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                            </Tab>
                    </Tabs>
```

But if i change to

```
<Tabs onSelect={(index, label) => console.log(label + ' selected')}>
                            {this.state.users.map(user=>
                                <Tab label={user} >
                                    <div className="table-scrollable table-scrollable-borderless">
                                        <table className="table table-hover table-light">
                                            <thead>
                                                <tr className="uppercase">
                                                    <th> # </th>
                                                    <th> First Name </th>
                                                </tr>
                                            </thead>
                                            <tbody>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td> 1 </td>
                                                    <td> Mark </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </tbody>
                                        </table>
                                    </div>
                                </Tab>
                            )}
                        </Tabs>
```

It gives me error

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined
>   TabsComponent._renderContent
>   C:/Users/repos/node_modules/react-bootstrap-tabs/dist/index.js:198

Answer (score 0, accepted):

12 hours in code makes sense.

I'm changing only **Tab**, but need to re-render whole element, starting from **Tabs** after page load

```
{!this.state.loading ? <UsersTabs users={this.state.users} /> : "Loading"}
```

With

```
class UsersTabs extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Tabs onSelect={(index, label) => console.log(label + ' selected')}>
                {this.props.users.map(market =>
                    <Tab label={user} >
                        ...
                    </Tab>
                )}
            </Tabs>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have data in your `users` state?
Looking at the code of the library on the error line:

`var contentClassNames = (0, _classnames2.default)('tab-content', this.props.contentClass, contentTab.props.className);`

I think it is trying to find a tab inside the `Tabs` component. If your `users` state is empty your map will result in an empty array.

Try adding a default tab besides the `this.users.map`, or if not a tab, at least a dummy element like a `<div/>` you can hide via css or perhaps a `<React.Fragment/>`.

Comment: Thank you for reply. Users is not empty, it's just simple Array(2)
0: "John"
1: "Mike"

Answer (score 0):

I think your users array is initially empty ([]). This makes the tabs component error out:

https://codesandbox.io/s/wyj88jky2k

You should check that this.state.users has entries before trying to render your tabs.

To be honest, I would expect the tabs library to be able to handle an empty tabs array - perhaps you could raise a bug on their github page.

Comment: Thank for your reply. My users array is not empty initially.

Comment: Dude - when I empty the array you get that exact error meassage. It must be empty at some point. Have you logged out the array before rendering it?